# Why two different calculations of inverse of homogeneous matrix give two different results?

Tags: c++, eigen, matrix-inverse, pcl

I'm processing some cloud point data in `pcl`. I want to transform cloud with a given homogeneous matrix, and then transform it back with inverse of that matrix. Here what I have done:

**transform forward**

```cpp
// transform
//    0.995965  -0.00315886   -0.0074089            0
//  0.00315886     0.995992 -1.17255e-05            0
//   0.0074089 -1.17255e-05      0.99597            0
//           0            0            0            1

pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloudPtr, *cloudTransformed, transform);
```

**transform back**

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix4f invtransform = transform;
invtransform.block<3,3>(0,0).transposeInPlace(); // take effect in place
invtransform.block<3,1>(0,3) = -invtransform.block<3,3>(0,0)*invtransform.block<3,1>(0,3);
// here get invtransform
//    0.995965   0.00315886    0.0074089           -0
// -0.00315886     0.995992 -1.17255e-05            0
//  -0.0074089 -1.17255e-05      0.99597            0
//           0            0            0            1
pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloudptr, *cloudback, invtransform);
```

Unfortunately, I get wrong result in **cloudback**.
But when I try following code to calculate inverse of matrix, it works:

```cpp
// the transform gives
//    0.995965  -0.00315886   -0.0074089            0
//  0.00315886     0.995992 -1.17255e-05            0
//   0.0074089 -1.17255e-05      0.99597            0
//           0            0            0            1
Eigen::Matrix4f invtransform = transform.inverse();
// now invtransofrom gives
//     1.00399    0.0031843   0.00746857           -0
//  -0.0031843      1.00401 -1.18674e-05            0
// -0.00746857 -1.18674e-05      1.00399           -0
          -0            0           -0            1
pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloudPtr, *cloudback, invtransform);
```

1. Why they are different results, and the former seems wrong?
2. Doesn't Inverse of homogeneous matrix to transform rigid body calculate as following:

R_inv = R.transpose;

t_inv = -1.0 * R_inv * t

where R an t stand for rotation and translation part of homogeneous matrix.

Comment: The inverse of a matrix is not just -1 * (the matrix). Here is a long article explaining how to  inverse the rotation part: https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Inverse-of-a-3x3-Matrix
But the seconf part is right, the beauty of a 4x4 homogeneous transform is that you can just inverse it and use it.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Sorry, I cannot understand *The inverse of a matrix is not just -1 * (the matrix)*, yes, I know it's true if it is just a normal matrix, but here are all homogeneous matrix if 4x4 matrices given. So if the second part stands, and why can't I use it to get inverse of a homogeneous matrix?

Comment: by second part, i was referring to `Eigen::Matrix4f invtransform = transform.inverse();` which is perfectly valid. Why don't you just use this?

Comment: It looks like your original transformation is not an Isometry. The shortcut with using `transpose()` instead of `inverse()` for the top-left 3x3 block only works if that part is really unitary, not for generic homogeneous matrices. I can't say if you actually have an Isometry, which got denormalized over time (e.g., due to accumulating numeric errors), or if you actually have a non-isometric transform.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Thanks, now I understand. Currently,  I‘m using `inverse()` version of `eigen` . But, I think both should work, given the homogeneous matrices. So I want to find where I'm wrong. Maybe due to some calculations(rotation is not a normalized matrix, so **inversion of it doesn't equal to transpose of it**, I'm digging into it), just as @chtz suggested.